# #define leads to the "Access violation reading location"

Tags: c++

I think this is child question but i can't find info how to solve it.

//*.h:

```
class Foo
{
    #if defined(RedefChallangesCount)
        static const mainDataType ChallangesCount = 500;
        #undef RedefChallangesCount
    #else
        static const mainDataType ChallangesCount = 1;
    #endif

    ...
    int _correctAnswers[ChallangesCount];

    ....
}
```

In my VS tests class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#define RedefChallangesCount
#include "..\Core\ChallengeManager.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace Brans;

namespace CoreTests
{
    TEST_CLASS(SomeTestClass)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(SomeTestMethod)
        {
            Foo* cm = new Foo();
            cm->Method();
            ...
            delete cm;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems for me that i do all like in docs, but when run test with #define RedefChallangesCount line i got strange errors like "Access violation reading location", sometimes bad array
_correctAnswers. At the same time i see that ChallangesCount is 500 as expected. If i comment #define RedefChallangesCount line - all errors gone...
What can be wrong?

Comment: Why do you need `#undef RedefChallangesCount`?

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without code that compiles.

Comment: Andrey> it doesn't matter. For me it is just promise - that i don't need it(RedefChallangesCount) any more in any place. I tried without that line - the same.

Comment: Do you ensure the dodgy macro is defined in *every* translation unit, including the one(s) that define the class member function(s)? Otherwise, you'll break the One Definition Rule and all kinds of things can go wrong.

Comment: Yes, the redefinition looks like the reason, when i defined RedefChallangesCount in the preprocessor properties of the test and main project errors are gone

Comment: What does this have to do with `#define`? Narrow down your problem please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  If understood your question, i want to change the value of the ChallangesCount for only one test. For example with the help of #define. Ideal variant - if i don't will change the code of tested class. Creation of separate solution configuration also is not good enough because  ChallangesCount = 500 will be for ALL TESTS, and i need for only one.

Comment: Don't worry; [nobody writes testcases any more](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `#undef` makes me suspicious that this header is being included elsewhere (e.g by `ChallengeManager.cpp`, meaning you'll end up with your `_correctAnswers` having a size of `500` in some places and `1` in others, which would certainly explain your crash.

(edit): Are your tests a separate project in the solution, with the main code in its own project, or is your code all compiled directly in the test project?

To be safe, set your `#define` in the VS build configuration (for all projects being linked into the tests - you'll need to add a Tests build config for this, and use it instead of Debug/Release for the test build) rather than defining it in code, and remove the `#undef`

Comment: Thanks. When i defined RedefChallangesCount in the preprocessor properties of the test and main project (that are separate projects) errors are gone

Comment: But that isn't good for me because i want to redefine that constant just for one test.

Comment: @BransDs: You *must* define it to the same value in both the test and the main project. If you don't want that, you have to redesign your class interface to pass it as a parameter, e.g. in the constructor.

Comment: @Andrey If i will define that for all tests that will make it slow.. Yes, i can't redesign main class, but i think that redesign just for test isn't good design. I looks for elegant solution. If this is impossible... then i will

Comment: @BransDs: To simplify testing is a very good reason for redesign.

Comment: @BranDs That's why I said in my answer that you need to add another build configuration with its own defines set

Comment: @benjymous Creation of separate solution configuration also is not good enough because  ChallangesCount = 500 will be for ALL TESTS, and i need for only one.

Comment: I prefer if it is possible to use one define... but it looks like isn't possible like i want.

Comment: @Andrey you say that i need to change code = object model  because i need this only in one test. It isn't good, it is necessary, maybe. Not good.

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to have `if defined` sections within code, especially class code.  I would tend to use a variable, and branch based on its value:

in the test class remove the `#define RedefChallangesCount` and replace with a global variable of `bool RedefChallangesCount`

Then your code becomes much simpler and can be as follows (simplified version for demonstration purposes):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool RedefChallangesCount = false;
int main()
{
    int ChallangesCount;
    cout << RedefChallangesCount << endl;
    if (RedefChallangesCount)
        ChallangesCount = 500;
    else
        ChallangesCount = 1;

   cout << ChallangesCount << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

as opposed to:

```
#if defined(RedefChallangesCount)
    static const mainDataType ChallangesCount = 500;
    #undef RedefChallangesCount
#else
    static const mainDataType ChallangesCount = 1;
#endif
```

However, let me know if using preprocessor is a requirement and then I can try and sort you out a solution using that methodology, though as I said, I don't use preprocessor directives for actual program flow (have to add *normally*, as guaranteed I have done it once for a valid reason, and cant remember).

Comment: I can't use if (RedefChallangesCount) construct in the header file to define the array length... Can you explain how to use this approach for this?

Comment: So long as you define the RedefChallangesCount variable before the instantiation of the Foo class you should be fine, and you can change the value of the RedefChallangesCount between versions so you can run multiple tests with either true or false as the RedefChallangesCount value. Let me know if you need more info and I can perhaps illustrate better with some exemplar code.